# How to make or share Google photos to public?

Tags: google-photos, picasa-web-albums

Since Google has decided to retire Picasa in order to focus on a single photo service in Google Photos – a new, smarter photo app that works seamlessly across mobile and the web.

Now there is only one question in everyone's mind. How to set the photo album "share to public" or How do I make an album public?

Comment: @pnuts: The referred question is obsolete as Google+ photos was retired. Google Photos doesn't work in the same way.

Comment: @pnuts: I didn't pay attention to the OP answers, my bad. Anyway, while the OP intention was to use it as spam seed, it's possible to answer it without spam. Anyway, IMHO, it should not be closed as duplicate of the referred Q.

Answer (score 0):

From [Share photos & videos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6131416?hl=en)

> Anyone that has the shared link will be able to see the album

Extract from the above link:

> **Send a link or share to other apps**
>
> 1. On your computer, open https://photos.google.com.
> 2. Place your cursor over a photo or video and click the check mark [image: Done].
>      You can also select other items, or open an album or movie.
> 3. Click Share [image: Share].
> 4. Send a link or select an app to share. You can also enter or select a name or email address.
> 5. Optional: You can also add a message when you share. To manage these messages, go to the [activity log](https://photos.google.com/activities/photos_messages).